# iOS - HTTP Method not making POST Request but instead making GET

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, urlsession

I'm trying to make a POST call in my app using URLSession (and AlamoFire) no luck with either, I'm checking the network call on Charles Proxy and it's always being sent as a GET call even though I've specified the HTTPMethod to be "POST" or .post in both.

Weirdest part is updating the call to "DELETE" or "PUT" will work...just not "POST" or .post

I've tried just building the request from ground up in URLSession instead of using AlamoFire, tried changing the HTTPMethod (which works, just not for POST)

let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: endpointURL)!

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let jsonData: Data = try! requestProto.serializedData()

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in
        print("request made")
    }

    task.resume()
```

Expected: Charles records a POST call
Actual: Charles is recording GET call for both GET and POST calls, but DELETE and PUT are working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this with URLSession

```swift
// create a `URLRequest` because post are urlRequest used with  urlSession.shared.uploadTask
var request = URLRequest(url: url) 

// here pass in data format the body of the request
request.httpBody = body 

// the request method.
request.httpMethod = "post" 

// required when send a json type in request
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") 

URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: nil) { (data, response, error) in
    let response = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode
    if (response! == 500 ){
        print("error")
    }
    print("request made")    
}.resume()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but make sure that you are sending https request (not http).

Comment: Please add more context on why https would work and not http.